# Flutter Reorderable List going back to it's original state

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite, reorderable-list

I made the list reorderable but now it's going back to its initial state. Can someone help me? My list consists of List Tile which is generated from the database using Asynsnapshot. The key I used is the same as the index. It seems like the insert function isn't inserting the note in the new index. Is it because the future builder is rebuilding?

```
body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.882,
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: databaseHelper.getNoteList(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Text('Loading');
                        } else {
                          if (snapshot.data.length < 1) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Text('No Messages, Create New one'),
                            );
                          }
                          return ReorderableListView(
                            children: List.generate(
                              snapshot.data.length,
                              (index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  key: Key('$index'),
                                  title: Text(
                                    snapshot.data[index].title,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].note,
                                      maxLines: 4),
                                  trailing: InkWell(
                                    child: Icon(Icons.add_box,
                                        color: Colors.green),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      TextEditingController txt =
                                          TextEditingController();

                                      txt.text = snapshot.data[index].note;
                                      print(txt);
                                      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              MyHomePage(custMessage: txt));
                                      Navigator.push(context, route);
                                      // addNewMessageDialog(txt);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  // isThreeLine: true,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => AddNote(
                                              note: snapshot.data[index],
                                            ));
                                    Navigator.push(context, route);
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                            onReorder: _onReorder,
                          );
                        }
                      }))
            ],
          )),
```

Reoder function

```
void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    var snapshot = await databaseHelper.getNoteList();

    if (newIndex > snapshot.length) newIndex = snapshot.length;
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex -= 1;
   
      setState(() {
        final Note item = snapshot[oldIndex];
        snapshot.removeAt(oldIndex);

        print(item.title);
        snapshot.insert(newIndex, item);
      });
   
  }
```

I tried adding future delay but no use.
[image] [image][image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You do not need to call `databaseHelper.getNoteList()` in `_onReorder` again 
You can use `noteList = snapshot.data;` and operate `noteList`

code snippet

```
void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    if (newIndex > noteList.length) newIndex = noteList.length;
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex -= 1;

    setState(() {
      final Note item = noteList[oldIndex];
      noteList.removeAt(oldIndex);

      print(item.title);
      noteList.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }
...
noteList = snapshot.data;
      return ReorderableListView(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Note {
  String title;
  String note;

  Note({this.title, this.note});
}

class databaseHelper {
  static Future<List<Note>> getNoteList() {
    return Future.value([
      Note(title: "1", note: "n1"),
      Note(title: "2", note: "n2"),
      Note(title: "3", note: "n3"),
      Note(title: "4", note: "n4"),
      Note(title: "5", note: "n5")
    ]);
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Note> noteList = [];
  Future<List<Note>> _future;

  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    if (newIndex > noteList.length) newIndex = noteList.length;
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex -= 1;

    setState(() {
      final Note item = noteList[oldIndex];
      noteList.removeAt(oldIndex);

      print(item.title);
      noteList.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _future = databaseHelper.getNoteList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.882,
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: _future,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Text('Loading');
                        } else {
                          if (snapshot.data.length < 1) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Text('No Messages, Create New one'),
                            );
                          }

                          noteList = snapshot.data;
                          return ReorderableListView(
                            children: List.generate(
                              snapshot.data.length,
                              (index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  key: Key('$index'),
                                  title: Text(
                                    snapshot.data[index].title,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].note,
                                      maxLines: 4),
                                  trailing: InkWell(
                                    child: Icon(Icons.add_box,
                                        color: Colors.green),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      /*TextEditingController txt =
                                      TextEditingController();

                                      txt.text = snapshot.data[index].note;
                                      print(txt);
                                      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              MyHomePage(custMessage: txt));
                                      Navigator.push(context, route);*/
                                      // addNewMessageDialog(txt);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  // isThreeLine: true,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    /*Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => AddNote(
                                          note: snapshot.data[index],
                                        ));
                                    Navigator.push(context, route);*/
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                            onReorder: _onReorder,
                          );
                        }
                      }))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `_onReorder` method, you create a new `snapshot` variable, then mutate that variable. Once `_onReorder` exits, this *local* `snapshot` variable is completely discarded. Thus, any mutations you apply to this local `snapshot` variable are also discarded.

Your confusion lies in that you have two completely distinct `snapshot` variables that are not coupled to each other: they only share the same name. In other words, changes applied to the `snapshot` variable in `_onReorder` have no effect on the variable in `build(BuildContext context)`.

You need to reference a single variable to track the state of the order of your list.

I've reproduced how you can do this by using a state variable and `initState` to initialize your state variable from a `Future`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Body())));

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  List<String> snapshot;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeSnapshot();
  }

  Future initializeSnapshot() async {
    final list = await getListFromDatabase();
    setState(() => snapshot = list);
  }

  Future getListFromDatabase() async {
    // In reality, you would make some network call here.
    return ["a", "b", "c"];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => snapshot == null
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : ReorderableListView(
          onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
            if (newIndex > snapshot.length) newIndex = snapshot.length;
            if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex -= 1;

            setState(() {
              final String item = snapshot[oldIndex];
              snapshot.removeAt(oldIndex);
              snapshot.insert(newIndex, item);
            });
          },
          children: snapshot
              .map((x) => ListTile(key: ValueKey(x), title: Text(x)))
              .toList(),
        );
}
```

Additionally: Don't use the index of an item in a list as the `Key` of a widget. This is because Flutter uses the key to determine if a widget at a particular index needs to be rebuilt. Instead, use a key that's unique to the *contents* of the widget, like `item.title` in your case.

Comment: item.title won't be unique in my case though. But thanks for your answer. I already got a working answer